# Unexpected end of JSON input error while running npm install command.Any fix to this issue?

Tags: json, angular6

I have been trying to run npm install to update my node modules,but couldn't !,none of the similar solutions work for me.

This is the error that I am getting:

[image: this is the error i am getting!]

Comment: This sort of error would point to there being an issue in your package.json file. There might be a bracket/comma etc missing. Are you developing in an editor such as VSCode/Atom etc? If you open the file in there it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, i did try that but there none of the above issue,I am using VS Code editor.still the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove cache using npm cache clean --force and try again.

Comment: Hi Nirali did try that ,didn't work for me!,any other option?